# What is the execution context of the function registered via the Wire.onReceive() method?

Tags: i2c

I'm basically wondering if it's OK to `Serial.write()` or print in the function I register to be called when I2C data is received.  I can't seem to find the execution context or any warnings.

http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/WireOnReceive

Answer (score 2):

Looking at `twi.c` in the Arduino libraries, it seems the callback function is called from within the I2C interrupt service routine (ISR). Any code in the call back will lengthen the ISR so it will have to be short. I don't think `Serial.write` will be too much of a problem; the TX interrupt will be delayed to the end of the I2C ISR which finishes straight after the callback and the `Serial.write` function is fairly short.

If you need to have a longer function run, you could instead have the callback store bytes in a ring buffer, then check for any available bytes in the main `loop()`.. but this is what the `Wire` class helps with already.

Comment: Serial.write blocks if the serial buffer is full and waits for the buffer to have room before continuing. Conveniently, Serial.write checks to see if interrupts are disabled when it runs; If they are disabled, it runs the interrupt routines itself when a new character needs written to make space in the buffer, preventing lockup. In any case, if the buffer is full, printing on serial can take as long as it physically takes to output that many characters.

Comment: @BrettM thanks, I'll edit question with that (or edit it yourself and I will accept)