# Wire Library send/receive

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c, wire-library

I'm doing a project that includes an Arduino Uno and custom hardware made by me. Everything is working perfectly independently, and I'm trying to implement a way for them (the Arduino and my hardware) to work together. In order to achieve that, I am using the Wire protocol (Arduino side) and I2C (custom hardware side). From now I can send data from **my hardware** to **my Arduino** in a **master-slave** relation, and I have no problem with that. Please take a look at my Arduino code for better understanding:

```c
void setup(void) {
  Wire.begin(7);
  Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent);
}

void receiveEvent(int howMany) {
  int x = Wire.read(); // receive byte as an integer
  Serial.print(x);
  if (x==0) 
    state = 0;
}
```

So far so good. Now I want to send data from the **Arduino** to my **custom hardware** full duple, and for that I am adding this code:

```c
void frame(void){
  Wire.write('x');
  Wire.write('\r');
}

void loop() {
  if (state == 0){
    frame();
    state = 1;
  }
}
```

In order to receive the 'x' char in my custom hardware I have switched the I2C protocol bit from Write to Read using `I2C_FORMAT_7_BIT_ADDRESS(SlaveAddress, _address, I2C_WRITE);` to `I2C_FORMAT_7_BIT_ADDRESS(SlaveAddress, _address, I2C_READ);` in my custom hardware code.

I don't know why, I am not receiving the data from the Arduino. Am I missing any configuration on the Arduino side?

Comment: Do I need any address in my custom hardware (I2C protocol) to receive data from the arduino side?

Comment: Who exactly is the master here? Who generates the clock? Full duplex means both devices can transmit simultaneously; this isnt possible with the I2C protocol. The Wire *library* is an Arduino implementation of the I2C protocol.

Comment: The master is my custom hardware (pic32mx) and the slave is the Arduino. So the master gives the clock which is 5khz for this case. I know they can not simultaneously but i AM trying to find a way for them to work in a question-answer way.

Answer (score 1):

I've not done events on an Arduino so this could be a bum steer, but shouldn't the state variable be volatile and protected with a semaphore?
You are accessing it in the main program and in your event/ISR.

Secondly, no offence intended, could you replace your hardware with a bit of tried and trusted hardware to eliminate the remote possibility that your hardware is at fault.

Comment: No, you don't need to have a variable defined as volatile and protected to access it in the main program and in any other event/method.
Let's not consider any possible problem with the hardware (which is a thing I don't believe because it's already a established product). What I really want to understand if it is possible to send and receive characters through Wire protocol as long as we have the Arduino defined as slave. I am receiving data with Wire.read and after that I am sending a chunk of chars using Wire.write but I am not getting that info in my hardware.

Comment: @scuba - in actuality, Matt's concern is probably correct.  The Arduino documentation is notoriously incomplete, but http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/4477/what-is-the-execution-context-of-the-function-registered-via-the-wire-onreceive suggests that the event methods are called in interrupt context, which means that the state variables they share with the main thread of execution do need to be volatile.  This is in contrast to something like SerialEvent() which occurs in the main thread of execution only between calls to loop().

Comment: However it looks as if your more primary issue may be that your code would respond to the write address by sending data, when what it needs to be doing is sending data in response to the read address that triggers the request event.

Answer (score 1):

You use the `onReceive()` and `onRequest()` methods of the Wire library to implement an Arduino slave. In your case, something like this:

```
void setup(void){
  Wire.begin(18);
  Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent);  # register receive handler
  Wire.onRequest(requestEvent);  #register request handler
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void receiveEvent(int howMany){
  int x = Wire.read();    // receive byte as an integer
  Serial.print(x);
  if (x == 0) 
    state = 0;
}

void requestEvent(){
  Wire.write("x\r");
  state = 1;
}
```

See [Slave Receiver](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/MasterWriter) and [Slave Sender](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/MasterReader) examples for more details.

Comment: How is the `requestEvent` is being called in this case? I already use the wire.write to send data to my hardware but I am not using the `requestEvent` at all. Is it really necessary?

Comment: `requestEvent` is called automatically whenever the master requests data from the slave. The Arduino is not in charge of the I2C bus; it must wait till the master begins driving the clock line and specifically asks for data. Only then should you use `Wire.write()` else nothing happens.

Comment: So from my Pic side which function should I use to request data from the arduino?

Comment: The same function you would use to read data from any I2C slave; from the PIC32, you simply send the address of the Arduino slave (7, in this case) followed by a 1 to indicate a READ operation and you wait till this is sent. At this point, the Arduino receives this byte and interprets it as a READ, calls `onRequest()` and begins to place data on the bus. Your PIC32 reads the data byte by byte until it is satisfied and then sends the STOP condition. I assume you've worked with I2C on the PIC32 before?

Comment: That's exactly what I am doing in the PIC32 side but it seems the READ operation is not taking effect in the arduino side and it's not calling the `onRequest()` arduino function automatically.

Comment: @scuba update your post with the pic32 i2c read function. Or provide a link.

Comment: The code is kinda big, how can I show you without putting all the code here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37934/discussion-between-tisteandii-and-scuba).

Comment: In case anyone's interested, I think the problem had to do with the slave I2C address. 0x7 is a reserved address so I've edited the answer to use an allowed address.